# How to configure rsync with password in OpenStack Swift

Tags: rsync, openstack-swift

I am currently working on Swfit. For safe, the op ask me to set password for rsync. 
While, as we use Swift, we just set rsync work as server with "/etc/rsync.conf" , then Swift works as the client without password.
So, my question is, if i start the rsync with "secrets file" option, which set the user:password. Then, how to set Swift with the password? 
Read the Swift code about the rsync in replicator, i can't find the option to set the password.
Or, Swift doesn't support the function?

Answer (score 0):

Luckly, by reading the source code, i find the way to support rsync with 'secrets file' option:
By adding the '--password-file=/your_passwd_file_path' to rsync order in this two function:
swift/common/db_replicator.py/_rsync_file() and swift/obj/replicator/rsync()
Then, restart your swift, it will work right.